# Binary search Tree using templates and reading in text files

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search-tree

I am completely lost on how to do this project. I have done what I know and searched the internet for things to help me finish this project, but I am almost hopeless at this point. If anyone could help me out and give me a very strong push in the right direction, that would be much appreciated. Okay here it is:

> Create a template based binary search tree, then use this tree as the
>   storage for a dictionary of words used to check the spelling of
>   documents.  The binary tree must have the following characteristics:
>
> It must be a binary search tree (BST), relying on the order of the `< >`
>   operators provided by whatever type the user of the tree chooses (in
>   other words, you don't have to do anything special, just use those
>   operators correctly).
>
> #### Public methods:
>
> ```
> bool insert(T value) : inserts a value into the tree, does not allow duplicates.  If the value is already in the tree do notadd the duplicate and return false, true otherwise.
>
> void remove(T value) : deletes a value from the tree.
>
> bool search(T value) : tests to see if a value exists in the tree.
>
> void display() : Performs an in-order traversal of the tree, displaying the value at each node.
>
> unsigned int numberNodes() : returns a count of all nodes in the tree.
>
> unsigned int numberLeafNodes() : returns a count of all the leaf nodes in the tree.
>
> unsigned int height() : returns the height of the tree.
> ```
>
> Write a driver program that reads the file “dictionary.txt”, where
>   each word is on a separate line, and stores these words into your
>   binary search tree.  After reading the dictionary into your tree, have
>   your program report the number of nodes, the number of leaf nodes, and
>   height (depth) of the tree.
>
> The following is an example report:
>
> **-- Tree Stats --**
>
> ***Total Nodes: 13643 Leaf Nodes:  4545 Tree Height: 30***
>
> Next, read the file “letter.txt” and output to the console all the
>   misspelled words (meaning any word not found in the dictionary), keep
>   in mind the graders will use a different file when doing the grading.
>   You'll need to remove case from the words and remove any punctuation
>   characters from the words in the letter; the following characters
>   should be sufficient: “ , : . ! ? ( )
>
> One problem you need to resolve: The dictionary is in alphabetic
>   order. If you insert the words in alphabetic order, your tree will
>   essentially be a linked list and of not much use (with respect to
>   performance). The words must be inserted in random order to make a
>   tree that can be efficiently searched.  A suggestion is to use the
>   std::random_shuffle algorithm in the C++ standard library. This will
>   randomly organize the values in a vector.  Then, you can iterate
>   through the vector and add items to your tree, resulting in a
>   reasonably balanced and efficient binary search tree.

Here is all I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <class T>

class Tree
{
    struct TreeNode
    {
        T data;
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* Right;

        TreeNode(T value) :data(value), left(NULL), right(NULL)
        {
            //empty
        }
    };
    TreeNode* root;
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    bool insert(T value);
    void remove(T value);
    bool search(T value);
    void display();
    unsigned int numberNodes();
    unsigned int numberLeafNodes();
    unsigned int height();

};

template <class T>
Tree<T>::Tree() :root(NULL) 
{
  //empty
}

template <class T>
Tree<T>::~Tree()
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    if (node->left)
        freeMemory(node->left);
    if (root->right)
        freeMemory(node->right);
    delete node;
}


template <class T>

bool Tree<T>::insert(T value)
{
    TreeNode* treeNode = NULL;

    temp = root;
    while (temp)
    {
        prev = temp;
        if (temp->data < treeNode->data)
        {
            temp = temp->right;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->left;
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        root = treeNode;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (prev->data < treeNode->data)
        {
            prev->right = treeNode;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->left = treeNode;
            return true;
        }
    }
}


template<class T>
void Tree<T>::remove(T value)
{

}

template<class T>
bool Tree<T>::search(T value)
{
    return false;
}

template<class T>
void Tree<T>::display()
{

}

template<class T>
unsigned int Tree<T>::numberNodes()
{
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
unsigned int Tree<T>::numberLeafNodes()
{
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
unsigned int Tree<T>::height()
{
    return 0;
}


int main()
{



    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TBH, you haven't really done anything, so it's very likely you will not receive a lot of help here.

Comment: I'm assuming `freeMemory` is a function you've defined somewhere?

Comment: Which `node` is the destructor (`~Tree`) referring to? Have you *tested* your code, such as it is?